# The partial derivatives seem continuous to me, but the function is not differentiable

Tags: calculus

For example in the following function:
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2},(x,y)\neq 0\\ 0,(x,y)=0\end{cases}$$

The partial derivatives in $(0,0)$
for $x$ and $y$ are $1$
therefore the derivative exists and is continuous at a point
but the function is not differentiable in $(0,0)$.

How is it possible?

Comment: So, partial derivatives are not the whole derivatives.

Comment: But this is a sufficient condition,If the partial derivatives exist and are continuous then the function is differentiable

Comment: Really, can you share a reference?

Comment: The partial derivatives are not continuous at $0$.

Comment: @BobDobbs In Italian it goes by the name *teorema del differenziale totale* ("total differential theorem"). Let $U\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be open, let $f:U\to \Bbb R$ (without assumptions on continuity) such that the partial derivatives exist on $U$ and let $x\in U$ such that the partial derivatives are continuous at $x$. Then, $f$ is differentiable at $x$. I don't know the English name.

Comment: Partial derivatives need not be continuous on U? Existance is enough? Interesting... I forgot these things.

Comment: @BobDobbs Not even $f$ needs to be continuous (although the partial derivatives need to exist in the neighbourhood). Continuity of the partial derivatives at $x$ is enough.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Can you show an example of such f?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define,
\begin{align*}
f:\mathbf{R}^{2}&\longrightarrow \mathbf{R},\\
(x,y)&\longmapsto \displaystyle\begin{cases}\frac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}},\quad (x,y)\not=(0,0),\\0,\quad (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}
\end{align*}

- Since $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f((0,0)+h(1,0))-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=1$$
  and
  $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f((0,0)+h(0,1))-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}=1$$
  So, indeed the partial derivative of $f$ there exists at $(0,0)$.
- However the differentiability requires something else and that is to ensure the following condition
  $$\color{blue}{\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f_{x}(0,0)(x-0)-f_{y}(0,0)(y-0)}{\sqrt{(x-0)^{2}+(y-0)^{2}}}=0}\quad (\star)$$
  But in this case we have
  \begin{align*}\frac{\frac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-x-y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}&=\frac{\frac{(r\cos \theta)^{3}+(r\sin \theta)^{3}}{r^{2}}-(r\cos \theta)-(r\sin \theta)}{\sqrt{r^{2}}},\quad \begin{cases}x=r\cos \theta,\\ y=r\sin \theta\end{cases} r\in \mathbf{R}_{+}^{*}, \theta \in [0,2\pi[,\\
  &=\frac{\frac{r^{3}(\cos^{3}\theta+\sin^{3}\theta)}{r^{2}}+r(-\cos \theta-\sin \theta)}{r},\\
  &=\frac{r}{r}\left(\cos^{3}\theta+\sin^{3}\theta-\cos\theta-\sin\theta\right),\\
  &=\cos^{3}\theta+\sin^{3}\theta-\cos\theta-\sin\theta
  \end{align*}
  Hence, for a example with $\theta=\pi/3\in [0,2\pi[$ we have
  $$\cos^{3}\frac{\pi}{3}+\sin^{3}\frac{\pi}{3}-\cos\frac{\pi}{3}-\sin\frac{\pi}{3}=-\frac{3}{8}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}\not=0$$
  Therefore $(\star)$  is not necessarily $0$, and so $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is clear

Answer (score 4):

No, the partial derivatives are not continuous in $(0,0)$. For $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$, you have:
$$f_x(x,y)=\dfrac{x\left(x^3+3y^2x-2y^3\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$
$$f_y(x,y)=\dfrac{y\left(y^3+3x^2y-2x^3\right)}{\left(y^2+x^2\right)^2}$$
And, as you correctly noticed, $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=1$. But:
$$\nexists\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f_x(x,y)$$
$$\nexists\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f_y(x,y)$$
For instance, consider $f_x(0,y)$ and $f_x(x,0)$ and similar restrictions for $f_y$.

Comment: Are $f_x$ and $f_y$ not undefined at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Since $f$ is ratio of differentiable functions for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$, we are sure that $f$ is differentiable for any $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and so we can evaluate the derivatives with the rules of differentiation. For $(x,y)=(0,0)$, we have no theorem that guarantee the differentiability and so we must proceed with the definition: that is, evaluating limit $f_x(0,0)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^3}{h^3}=1$. Similarly for $f_y(0,0)$. Hence, $f$ is differentiable in $(0,0)$ as well with derivatives $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The partial derivatives are not continuous at $(0,0)$:

$f$ is not even differentiable at $(0,0)$, since it is homogeneous of degree $1$ but not linear.